# PHP date conversion

Tags: php, date

I have date in format `2011-01-28 06:34:33` i.e. `date("Y-m-d H:i:s")`. I want to convert it into `28th January 2011`.

How can I change it?

Comment: -1 for not taking the time to look at the [manual for `date`](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and for not [searching StackOverflow first](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=convert+date+php). How to convert and format dates has been asked and answered countless times before. Please do not ignore [Ask Advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice)

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP convert one date into another date format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/php-convert-one-date-into-another-date-format)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supply the date function with your format, which can be found [here](http://php.net/date). Pass the timestamp of your original date as the second parameter to date. You can obtain the timestamp by using [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime).

```
date("dS F Y", strtotime("2011-01-28 06:34:33"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$dateStr = date("jS F Y", time());
```

The day value is without leading zero.

Answer (score 0):

Try this   echo date('jS F Y h:i:s A');