# Timestamp to Date

Tags: php, date

Ho do I convert:

2010-12-24 11:39:43

to:

24/12 11:39

Thanks.

Comment: To parse the input time: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: To format the output: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP date conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544502/php-date-conversion). Please do not ignore http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice

Comment: @Gordon - in the question you link to, you have a comment which says that it is a possible duplicate also, of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/php-convert-one-date-into-another-date-format, which may have been the one you meant all along.

Answer (score 5):

This should to the trick:

```
$newFormat = Date ( 'd/m H:i', StrToTime ( '2010-12-24 11:39:43' ) );
```

You use [StrToTime](http://php.net/strtotime) to convert a string representation of a date to timestamp. You then feed that timestamp to the [Date](http://php.net/date) function that takes the format of the date as the first parameter.

Comment: Why does the contribution with the most explanation have the least upvotes? The mysteries of voting... :)

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
$unixtime = strtotime("2010-12-24 11:39:43");

$newFormat = date("d/m H:i", $unixtime);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
echo date("d/m H:i", strtotime("2010-12-24 11:39:43"));
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to convert the timestamp using strtotime().

Answer (score 1):

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d G:i:s', 2010-12-24 11:39:43); //You can simply tell DateTime accept your timestamp as is since PHP 5.3

echo $date->format('d/m G:i T'); //Will output what you wanted + Timezone Abbreviation (because of the T)
```

Comment: ^In 5.3, you can pass your datetime as is using new DateTime rather than using the DateTime Static function I provided. I personally think that's easier than the two methods above; The way above showed you how to always get out of situation where you think you have a unique DateTime.